# Smart card error from Remote Desktop app

Tags: smartcard, remote-desktop

On Windows 10 there are two apps to remotely connect to another computer. One is old Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) and the other is modern Remote Desktop (RdClient.Windows.exe hidden somewhere in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps). I have my own application on remote computer.

- With the old mstsc.exe I can connect to remote host (Windows 7) and use local smart card reader in my app. `SCardEstablishContext` works.
- With the new RdClient I can connect alright, but a call to `SCardEstablishContext` returns 0x8010001d (SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE).

Why is this happening for RdClient and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @tzippy No. Using old Remote Desktop Connection instead of the new one.

Comment: Thanks! My problem tho is that I get the error on both clients.